# Slack API (JSON Data)

Tags: javascript, json, slack-api, slack

I'm trying to use [this method](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info/test) provided via the Slack API to grab the "name" attribute of the "user" object and the code I'm using to do that is as follows:

```
controller.hears(['users'], 'direct_message, direct_mention, mention', function(bot, message){
bot.api.users.info({}), function(err, response) {
bot.reply(message, response);
var slack_username = message["user"][2];
console.log(">>>>> " + slack_username);
});
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong/missing and any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Expected Output: "dkulas"

Terminal Output" "U"

debug: Got response null {"OK":false,"error":"user_not_found"}

degub: SAY { ok: false, error: 'user_not_found', channel" 'D0UV5S7MZ' }

Comment: Please include the output you're expecting, and the output or errors you're getting.

Comment: Don't you need to pass parameters into `bot.api.users.info({})`? I don't see any part of your code where you're passing the Slack user id. The user id should start with a "U"

Comment: I believe the ID starts with a 'U', I'm trying to get the username a Slack user picks when they sign up, i.e. joesmith.  And I can't pass it a literal user id/name, that defeats the purpose of trying to capture it.  How can I provide the parameter if I don't know what it is?  It could be any number of usernames, depending on who is using the script at any given time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Slack API method `users.info` requires you to provide the Slack User ID in the query. The format is `U12345678`. (also see [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) for the usage documentation)

If you want to get the user info for a user by name, use the API method `users.list` to get the list of all users including name and user ID and then search that list for the right match. `users.list` provides all information about a user, so you don't need to call `user.info`.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) for the documentation on this method.